# Display "add to cart" button on every listing in product category page?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, archives, buttons

I need to place **Add to cart** button at every product on the page of certain category as shown below
[image: page's screenshot]

How can I achive this?
Link to subject page [oma-fintess.com.ua](https://oma-fitness.com.ua/orbitreki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more">More info</a><?php
if($available){?><a href="<?php
                $add_to_cart = do_shortcode('[add_to_cart_url id="'.$post->ID.'"]');
                echo $add_to_cart;
?>" class="more">Buy now</a>
                    <?php 
                }
```

This code solve my problem as expected.

[WooCommerce documentation reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-15)

Comment: Could you explain where you put this code ?

Comment: You have to place that code in product's page template as far as I remember.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the WooCommerce hook `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button`. This hook will add content after the "Add To Cart" button.

If the customer clicks on this button, the product should get added to the cart, and the customer should be send to the checkout page.

Add the below code in your child theme `functions.php`

```
/* Create Buy Now Button dynamically after Add To Cart button */
    function add_content_after_addtocart() {
    
        // get the current post/product ID
        $current_product_id = get_the_ID();
    
        // get the product based on the ID
        $product = wc_get_product( $current_product_id );
    
        // get the "Checkout Page" URL
        $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    
        // run only on simple products
        if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
            echo '<a href="'.$checkout_url.'?add-to-cart='.$current_product_id.'" class="buy-now button">Buy Now</a>';
            //echo '<a href="'.$checkout_url.'" class="buy-now button">Buy Now</a>';
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple solution for it.

```
$product_object = wc_get_product( $product_id );
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $product_object->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="buy-now button">' . esc_html__( 'Buy Now', 'text-domain' ) . '</a>';
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks @Loosie94

Answer (score 0):

Please make  sure that “Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives” is turned on in **WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display**.

Also please Check following code place in to your theme function file.

```
add_action( ‘woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item’, ‘woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart’, 10 );
```

Comment: @pratik-pratel No, it doesn't work for me at all in my case.
May be you missing some part of your code when paste it?
I guess I should use 
    `<?php 
echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="'.$post->ID.'"]');
?> ` but how can I apply button style to this shortcode?

Comment: You must try this   [add_to_cart id="27" style="border-right:1px solid #ccc"]

Comment: If you're overriding any existing styles you'll have to write
.woocommerce .product .add_to_cart_button.button{
 background-color: #333333;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

Comment: @pratik-pratel I may guess that you had copy and little bit modify your advice from https://jonathanbossenger.com/adding-the-cart-button-to-your-divi-shop-pages/, wasn't you  ?